# ReactJS responsive layout unresponsive for first grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the following code for App.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';


const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
      },   

  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

class App extends Component {        
    render() {
        return (
            <main>
                <div class="root">
                            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                            <Grid item xs={6}>
                            <TextField
                                id="filled-name"
                                label="First Name"                                  
                                margin="normal"
                                variant="filled"
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <TextField
                                id="filled-name"
                                label="Last Name"
                                margin="normal"
                                variant="filled"
                                />   
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

                    </div>
            </main>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

But during inspect element responsive setting, the First Name box is not responsive and if I select different mobile screen options, the layout is not always as intended.

Can someone please opine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow the documentation correctly

1) You are using class instead of className.

2) You are not using styles object and also withStyles higher order component.

`Demo.js` file for reference:- and working [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/457jj8wq4)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },

  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    width: 100
  }
});

class Demo extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <main>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Grid container spacing={24}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                id="filled-name"
                label="First Name"
                margin="normal"
                variant="filled"
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <TextField
                id="filled-name"
                label="Last Name"
                margin="normal"
                variant="filled"
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Demo);
```

Hope that helps!!!